# Is there a shortcut for viewing diff details in a git submodule instead of commit hashs?

Tags: git

If one creates a git submodule with `git submodule add [remote URL]` and commits in the submodule, `git diff` in the parent project shows something like

```
diff --git a/validation-tools b/validation-tools
index 78208b2..8941219 160000
--- a/validation-tools
+++ b/validation-tools
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 78208b2e64422a85509f0462b944ef8fbde93f48
+Subproject commit 8941219dd4935e97a585295ec34fb190e601b7ab
```

In order to view the different in the submodule one has to `cd` into it and copy the two hashes as arguments to `git diff` or `git difftool`. I'm looking for a shortcut which avoids the copying (and the `cd` if possible).

I'm using `git` 2.11.0 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
git diff --submodule=diff
```

However, in the version of Git that you're using (2.11), this command will fail if your submodules have nested submodules within them. ([Version 2.14.1 resolves this issue](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5221427cb8b78c3246ffa305900db935017c54), however.)

If, for some reason, you can't upgrade your Git and you have nested submodules, you could try:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git diff --name-status
```